# ¿Cómo borrar un marker en un mapa Leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Si tendría algún código o sabe de algún método para borrar un marker uno por uno?
Sólo necesito saber o darme una idea de cómo borrarlo, por favor!

Por ejemplo (en la aplicación tiene un mapa y un checkbox "Borrar un marker"), entonces, un usuario agrega uno o más marcadores en el mapa y si el usuario quiere borrar un marker entonces le da click en el checkbox ("Borrar un marker"), después da click en un marcador "indeseado" y se borra.

**Ui.R**

```
...
...
checkboxInput("addMarker", "Add new hospital"),
      checkboxInput("removeMark","Remove a marker"),  
      actionButton("clearMarkers", "Clear all markers"),

      strong(textOutput("message"))

....
```

**Server.R**

```
...
...
...
v <- reactiveValues(msg = "")

  df_r <- reactiveValues(new_data = datf)
  clicked_markers <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker = NULL) 
  observeEvent(input$map_click, { 

    click<- input$map_click 
    click_lat <- click$lat
    click_long <- click$lng

    clicked_markers$clickedMarker <- c(clicked_markers$clickedMarker, 1) 
    id <- length(clicked_markers$clickedMarker) 

    v$msg <- paste("Add marker in: ",input$map_click$lat, ",", input$map_click$lng)

    if (input$addMarker) {
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat, layerId = id) #layerid

        df_r$new_data <- rbind(rep(NA,ncol(datf)), df_r$new_data)
        df_r$new_data$longitude[1] <- click_long
        df_r$new_data$latitude[1] <- click_lat
        df_r$new_data$existing[1] <- click_long


        #if (input$removeMark) {
          #leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
        #         removeMarker(input$map_click)

         # }

        }
  })

  output$tabledata <- renderDataTable({
    df_r$new_data

  })

  observeEvent(input$map_zoom, {
    v$msg <- paste("Zoom changed to", input$map_zoom)
  })
  observeEvent(input$map_bounds, {
    v$msg <- paste("Bounds changed to", paste(input$map_bounds, collapse = ", "))
  })
  observeEvent(input$clearMarkers, {

    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearMarkers()
  })

  observeEvent(input$removeMark, {
    if (input$removeMark) {
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        removeMarker() ## ¿?

    }
  })
  output$message <- renderText(v$msg)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un `Marker` lo remueves usando `removeMarker()` esta función requiere al menos que le indiques:

- **map**: el objeto mapa creado por `leaflet()`
- **layerId**: Un vector de caracteres con el `id` del `marker`a remover

Por ejemplo si quisiéramos implementar un `checkbox` que al marcarlo muestre el `marker` y al desmarcarlo lo elimine del mapa, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
 observeEvent(input$show1, {
        proxy <- leafletProxy('map')
        if (!input$show1) {
            removeMarker(proxy, layerId = df$id[1])
        } else {       
            add_a_marker(proxy, 1)
        }
    })
```

Un ejemplo funcional completo podría ser este:

```
library("leaflet")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput("show1", "Mostrar ID=1", value = TRUE),
        checkboxInput("show2", "Mostrar ID=2", value = TRUE),
        checkboxInput("show3", "Mostrar ID=3", value = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(leafletOutput("map"))
)))

df <- data.frame(
    id = as.character(c(1, 2, 3)),
    lat = c(-31.8978827, -32.0499984, -30.9759958),
    lng = c(-64.7816031, -65.0348689, -64.512675)
)

add_a_marker <- function(proxy, id) {

    return(addCircleMarkers(
        proxy,
        layerId = df$id[id],
        df$lng[id],
        df$lat[id],
        group = 'marker',
        radius = 10,
        fill = TRUE,
        color = 'red'
    ))
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet(
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(
                layerId = df$id,
                df$lng,
                df$lat,
                group = 'marker',
                radius = 10,
                fill = TRUE,
                color = 'red'
            )
    )

    observeEvent(input$show1, {
        proxy <- leafletProxy('map')
        if (!input$show1) {
            removeMarker(proxy, layerId = df$id[1])
        } else {       
            add_a_marker(proxy, 1)
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$show2, {
        proxy <- leafletProxy('map')
        if (!input$show2) {
            removeMarker(proxy, layerId = df$id[2])
        } else {       
            add_a_marker(proxy, 2)
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$show3, {
        proxy <- leafletProxy('map')
        if (!input$show3) {
            removeMarker(proxy, layerId = df$id[3])
        } else {       
            add_a_marker(proxy, 3)
        }
    })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```